# Disable Ringtone for outbound Calls - earlyMedia: false

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I'm a beginner and we have a few Queues, when we make an outbound call from the "everyone" queue we are getting a loud Ringtone.
I got to know that I need to update **earlyMedia: false**
But I couldn't figure out on which function I have to update that.

Note: we are using Conference

I found a function related to this : name: **Flex Dialpad Call Outbound Join**
not sure if it is right

I Tried searching on the Functions with earlyMedia - But I couldn't figure out which function is exactly triggered here.